# Private (Fee Paying) schools in Finland

Tags: education, finland

This article from [2021](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-49825925) fact checks the statement that Finland abolished it's private education sector over a period of 10 years from the 1970s.

> Until the early 1970s in Finland, most secondary schools were run by private organisations. They were gradually brought under public control over the course of the decade, as part of wide-reaching educational changes, and their governing bodies were abolished.

Is there a record or summary of the public discussion and attitudes to this change; before, during and after the removal of fee paying schools?

I'm prepared to be told this is better suited to history, but it seems currently relevant given the current political discourse in the UK.